# Multiple Hard disks raid 1 adding space?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, disk-management

I'm a total noob to Ubuntu. So much so, I'm not even sure how to ask the question. Best to describe the situation I guess. I have an Ubuntu server 16.04LTS set up with 2 hard drives 1 500Gb 1 250Gb. I followed some Youtube videos to set up Samba and Raid1 software. I partitioned the raid drives to match, 2 at 230.9 plus swap space to total about 250Gb each (identically set up). I don't seem to have any problems with that, but I can't figure out how to access the additional 250ishGB from the second drive. How do I mount a partition outside of the raid configuration? Or is it wasted space because it's not in the array? If the later is the case, I guess I'd prefer to remove the raid array and just have 2 mounted disks totaling 750Gb. Can I do that without losing data on the disks? I'm running out of space.
PS. I don't know exactly what to search for, but I tried a couple before posting this question :^) Apologies if it's an often asked question.
Oh, this may help. Information is good, right?

root@Media-Server:/home/Bruce# mdadm -D /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
        Version : 1.2
  Creation Time : Sun Mar 25 13:07:52 2018
     Raid Level : raid1
     Array Size : 242056192 (230.84 GiB 247.87 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 242056192 (230.84 GiB 247.87 GB)
   Raid Devices : 2
  Total Devices : 2
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Intent Bitmap : Internal

```
Update Time : Fri Jun 22 12:14:29 2018
      State : clean
```

Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 0

```
       Name : Media-Server:0  (local to host Media-Server)
       UUID : cd8f05a6:12196b3e:11780858:b041ed79
     Events : 1743

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State<br>
   0       8        2        0      active sync   /dev/sda2
   1       8       19        1      active sync   /dev/sdb3
```

root@Media-Server:/home/Bruce# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           354M   15M  339M   5% /run
/dev/md0        228G  191G   26G  89% /
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           354M     0  354M   0% /run/user/1002

root@Media-Server:/home/Bruce# lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME    FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                       232.9G
├─sda1  swap                1.9G [SWAP]
└─sda2  linux_raid_member   231G            Media-Server:0
  └─md0 ext4              230.9G /
sdb                       465.8G
├─sdb1                        1K
├─sdb2  swap                1.9G [SWAP]
├─sdb3  linux_raid_member   231G            Media-Server:0
│ └─md0 ext4              230.9G /
└─sdb5                    232.9G

Thanks in Advance!